# Django Forms - Get object if exist - Unique Field - M2M

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, m2m

I'm still a junior with django. Please explain in detail :D

I'm developing a system to manage Full Days for restaurants. A full day can have many guests, and a guest can have many full days. M2M Relationship.

My model classes:

```
class Full_day(models.Model):

    by = models.ForeignKey('users.System_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    guests = models.ManyToManyField('users.Guest', verbose_name='Huespedes')
    business_unit = models.ForeignKey(
        'administration.Business_unit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Unidad de Negocio')
    type_full_day = models.ForeignKey(cat_full_day, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created = models.DateField(
        auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name='Creado el')
    modified = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Modificado el')

class Guest(models.Model):
    stature_choices=(
        ('+ 1.20', '+ 1.20 M'),
        ('- 1.20', '- 1.20 M')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nombre')
    document_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, verbose_name='Cedula/Documento Identidad', blank=True, null=True)
    stature = models.CharField(verbose_name='Estatura', choices = stature_choices, max_length=6)

    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name='Creado el')
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Modificado el')
```

**The problem**: as you can see the `document_id` must be unique, I want to make the view get to the guest if it already exists, to update it and assign it to the full day.

The number of guests for the Full day depends on the type of full day, I have already solved it with a GET (see it in the View), and I have rendered the amount of GuestForm's according to this.

I need help in the validation logic.

If there's a better way to do it, maybe with a CreateView I could use it too!

Thank you!

```
def Test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cat = request.GET['cf']
        typefd = cat_full_day.objects.get(pk = cat)

        fform = Full_dayForm(request.POST)
        gforms = [GuestForm(request.POST, prefix=str(x)) for x in range(typefd.guests)]

    #MAGIC HERE
    #IF GUEST IN FORM EXIST UPDATE AND ASSING TO FULL_DAY
    #THEN SAVE

    elif (request.method == 'GET'):        
        cat = request.GET['cf']
        typefd = cat_full_day.objects.get(pk = cat)
        fform = Full_dayForm()
        gforms = [GuestForm(prefix=str(x)) for x in range(typefd.guests)]
        context = {
            'typefd' : typefd,
            'fform' : fform,
            'gforms' : gforms,
        }

        return render(request, 'full_days/new_full_day.html', context)
    else:
        redirect('full_days:index')
```